# retrieving link using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I tried to go inside the link 'original' of this url.
It is url + 'AHS_' (for first item)

```
url = http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/


html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
print (soup)

for item in soup.find_all('a'):
  result = item['href']
  print (result)
```

However, it is giving excess information.

How can I get 'AHS_/' as the result

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to get URL from "original" link where the ID is "AHS"?

Comment: yes, it is also OK

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question, especially if that data is from an external resource.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment, here is script that obtains link from the row with ID *"AHS"* with text *"original"*:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = " http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/"

soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser' )

link = soup.select_one('td:contains("AHS") ~ td:has(a:contains("original")) a')['href']
print(link)
```

Prints:

```
http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/AHS_
```

---

EDIT: To parse all links:

```
for tr in soup.select('table tr:has(a)'):
    tds = tr.select('td')
    if len(tds) != 4:
        continue
    print('{:<10} {}'.format(tds[0].text, tr.select_one('a')['href']))
```

Prints (ID and first "original" link):

```
AHS        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/AHS_
EGT        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/EGT_
FHK        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/FHK_
GDK        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/GDK_
HVT        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/HVT_
KBF        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/KBF_
KEW        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/KEW_
LAM        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/LAM_
LBR        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/LBR_
MMF        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/MMF_
MSE        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/MSE_
MTK        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/MTK_
PFA        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/PFA_
RHN        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/RHN_
SGD        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/SGD_
SHA        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/SHA_
SSP        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/SSP_
TFS        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TFS_
TGF        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TGF_
TKC        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TKC_
TKY        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TKY_
TOC        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TOC_
TOE        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TOE_
TOS        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TOS_
TSE        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TSE_
UAK        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/UAK_
URY        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/URY_
YGT        http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/YGT_
```

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. i need to get others as well. EGT_.....